# Displaced ViewTransition not triggered in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

So I have a ListView and ListModel to which I'm adding objects dynamically. I want a `displaced` animation to happen to when a new object is added, but from what I can see, only the `add` transition is triggered and the `displaced` transition is never triggered. Based on the tutorial, this works:

```
  Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        ListView {
          width: 240; height: 320
          model: ListModel {
              id: model
          }

          Component {
              id: del
              Row {
                  height: 20
                  spacing: 20
                  Text { text: name }
                  Text { text: age }
              }
          }

          delegate: del

          add: Transition {
              NumberAnimation { property: "opacity"; from: 0; to: 1.0; duration: 1000 }
          }

          displaced: Transition {
              NumberAnimation { properties: "x,y"; duration: 1000; easing.type: Easing.OutBounce }
          }

          focus: true
          Keys.onSpacePressed: model.insert(0, { "name": "Item " + model.count, "age":21})
        }
    }
```

But this only triggers the `add` transition.

```
        Rectangle {
            height: 500
            width: 0.90 * parent.width
            anchors {
                top: parent
                topMargin: 30
                left: parent.left
                leftMargin: 45
            }
            ListView {
                anchors.fill: parent
                model: notificationModel
                delegate: notificationDelegate
                spacing: 30

                add: Transition {
                    NumberAnimation { property: "opacity"; from: 0; to: 1; duration: 1000 }
                }
                displaced: Transition {
                    NumberAnimation { properties: "x,y"; duration: 1000; easing.type: Easing.OutBounce }
                }
            }
        }

        ListModel {
            id: notificationModel
            Component.onCompleted: {
                    notificationModel.append({"name": "Tony"})
                }
        }

        Timer {
            interval: 5000; running: true; repeat: true
            onTriggered: notificationModel.append({"name": "Stark"})
        }

        Component {
            id: notificationDelegate
            Row {
                spacing: 20
                Text { text: name; color: "white" }
            }
        }
```

Any idea why this happens? Thanks!

Comment: please provide an example that could be run and compiled, what is  backend_service? I can't run it to find your bug and test it. Please clarify the question and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R hey, I made some changes that should make it easier. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `displaced` transition is triggered when an item in the list is forced to move because another item is added/removed/etc. The working example works because a single item gets inserted at the beginning of the list causing the remaining items to be displaced.

With the current code you are showing, the problem is that you are using the `append` function instead of `insert`. Append adds items to the bottom of the list, so no items are getting displaced.

Before you edited your question, you had a different problem. You were using `insert` to add items to the beginning of the list, but every time you added one, you were clearing the entire list and rebuilding it. So again, nothing was getting displaced because the entire list was getting recreated every time.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. The reason I was clearing the list was because I didn't want unseen notifications to be added twice. Do you have any suggestions on how I could solve that?

Comment: Without more context, I don't see how I can help. Why would they be added twice? What does it even mean to be "unseen"? If it's too big of an explanation, then it should probably be posted as a new question.